# Modify getter for Swift optional variable

Tags: swift

I have optional String. What is want is, when trying to access it variable throw an error if it nil or empty. I want something like:

```
var myString: String? {
    get {
    guard !self.isEmpty || self == nil else { // throw error }
    return self
    }
}
```

Is it possible to write such in Swift? Thanks.

Comment: just a side note - `self` can never be nil

Comment: @MilanNosáľ it's optional. How it could not be nil? I don't know syntax though

Comment: if self is nil you will not be able to access myString anyways (i.e. the block won't be ever executed)

Comment: @EvgeniyKleban you'd better explain what you want to achieve, as the (non-compilable) code you provided doesn't help us understand the problem

Comment: and show context, how are you planning on accessing myString? *Why* would you want to throw an exception in the first place?

Comment: @evgeniy-kleban : You can not throw error from getter of a variable yet read : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32899346/how-do-i-declare-that-a-computed-property-throws-in-swift-2

Comment: @Cristik ok, i just wan to show what i want to achieve with that code.

Comment: @EvgeniyKleban, what do you think `self` stands for in your snippet? what is _optional_ in your snippet in your view?

Comment: `self` stands for current object.. based on `return self` and return type of string one could assume you are trying to add a `myString` property to the `String` itself.. is that true?

Comment: I suggest you rather show us what you trying to do - where are you trying to use `myString` property and how? what are you trying to prevent?

Comment: @luk2302 by self i mean string i set getter for.

Comment: getter is supposed to provide access to a property of `self`, not to `self`..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First notice that `myString` cannot be `nil` as it is not an optional. If you want to allow storing `nil` declare it as an optional:

```
var myString: String?
```

checking for `self == nil` is redundant since if `self` is `nil` this property can never be accessed AND you cannot throw an exception from a computed property so throwing won't work either.

You can declare it as `private` and provide a getter method that can check if its `nil` or empty and throw accordingly
    }

If you do not want `myString` to ever be `nil` then do not declare it as optional. If you do not want the string to be empty than avoid that when setting the string.

```
private(set) myString: String // You cannot set the string directly outside of the class but you can access it freely

func setMyString(withValue value: String)
{
    if (value.isEmpty)
    {
        throw ... // 
    }

    myString = value
}
```

regarding throwing errors check this [link](https://medium.com/@abhimuralidharan/error-handling-in-swift-d0a618499910)

Comment: ok, how to do that - You can declare it as private and provide a getter method that can check if its nil or empty and throw accordingly } ? Can you provide compiling code snippet?

Comment: is it neccessary to make it private(set) ?

Comment: not necessary but then the string can be manipulated from outside the class and then any value (including empty string) can be stored in it

Answer (score 1):

In swift, **a computed property cannot throw an exception** - if you want to be sure, check out [Throwing Functions and Methods](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Declarations.html) section of Swift 4.1 language reference. So even if the rest of your code made sense, you simply cannot throw an exception from a computed property.

Anyway, test `self == nil` makes no sense - **`self` cannot really ever be nil**. If an object is nil, it does not exist, thus you cannot access any of its properties/methods (it does not exist, what would you be accessing?).

E.g., if you try to call `yourObject?.myString`, the getter for `myString` will NOT be executed at all, because `yourObject` is nil, it does not exist. If you try to force it using `!` it will crash right away.